# Static linking util-linux - cross-compiling (produces dynamically linked files instead)

Tags: linux, arm

I have been trying to cross compile util-linux for arm but I keep ending up with dynamically linked executable files and I don't know why is this. My objective is static. I have been cross-compiling before different tools using similar steps and it has always worked so I don't know what I am doing wrong this time. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Here are the commands I am running:

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export ac_cs_linux_vers=4
export CFLAGS=-static
export CPPFLAGS=-static
export LDFLAGS=-static

./configure --host=arm-linux LDFLAGS=-static --disable-shared --without-tinfo --without-ncurses --disable-ipv6 --disable-pylibmount --enable-static-programs=fdisk,sfdisk,whereis --prefix=/opt/util-linux/arm --bindir=/opt/util-linux/arm/bin --sbindir=/opt/util-linux/arm/sbin
```

As you can see, I specified static at every place I could think of even repeating stuff "just to make sure it understands me" and after I run the configure script, here is the output:

```
util-linux  2.28.2

prefix:            /opt/util-linux/arm
exec prefix:       ${prefix}

localstatedir:     ${prefix}/var
bindir:            /opt/util-linux/arm/bin
sbindir:           /opt/util-linux/arm/sbin
libdir:            ${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir:        ${prefix}/include
usrbin_execdir:    ${exec_prefix}/bin
usrsbin_execdir:   ${exec_prefix}/sbin
usrlib_execdir:    ${exec_prefix}/lib

compiler:          arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
cflags:            -static
suid cflags:       
ldflags:           -static
suid ldflags:      

Python:            /usr/bin/python
Python version:    2.7
Python libs:       ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Bash completions:  /usr/share/bash-completion/completions
Systemd support:   no
Btrfs support:     yes

warnings:
```

Then I do:

```
make fdisk
```

or

```
make whereis
```

and once the compilation is done, I do:

```
file fdisk
```

**fdisk** being the file that just got created and:

```
fdisk: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=369363ef8f8173a3a1c2edc178eb77255a2dc415, not stripped
```

As you can see it says, "dynamically linked". I have been searching all over the Internet but I failed to find an answer. I also do:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux LDFLAGS=-static --disable-shared --without-tinfo --without-ncurses --disable-ipv6 --disable-pylibmount --prefix=/opt/util-linux/arm --bindir=/opt/util-linux/arm/bin --sbindir=/opt/util-linux/arm/sbin
```

Which is exactly the same configure command as the one before that except for the missing "--enable-static-programs" parameter which "should" by default compile everything as static except that it does not.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a Makefile error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured out why the original commands posted in my question weren't producing static files! I had to run **make LDFLAGS="--static**". After I did this, everything linked statically!

To repeat, I ran:

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export ac_cs_linux_vers=4
export CFLAGS=-static
export SUID_CFLAGS=-static
export SUID_LDFLAGS=-static
export CPPFLAGS=-static
export LDFLAGS=-static
```

then

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --disable-shared --without-tinfo --without-ncurses --disable-ipv6 --disable-pylibmount --prefix=/opt/util-linux/arm --bindir=/opt/util-linux/arm/bin --sbindir=/opt/util-linux/arm/sbin
```

and then

```
make LDFLAGS="--static"
```

and everything linked statically! No more need for object files collection as demonstrated in my previous answer but yeah that too can be used as an alternative.

Also for your info, here is my version info as some of you will probably care:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ arm-linux-androideabi-ld --version
GNU gold (GNU Binutils 2.25.90.20151125) 1.11
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, this indeed works. The way I understand it, the various tools are compiled through `libtool` which pre-processes the compiler command line, and it happens to drop `-static` (single dash, there is a comment that static used to be same as `-all-static`, but that caused issues on some systems). Libtool won't touch double-dash options, that's why your solution works. I believe `make CFLAGS=-all-static` is what you want here, as that should build in exactly the same way as the tools for which there's native static build support. In any case, GNU tooling sucks.

Answer (score 1):

The static binaries are built with a `.static` extension; after the build, I get

```
$ file fdisk.static
fdisk.static: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=b51ec4b17f772b881d2a1eaefd368cfb96d0db12, not stripped
```

I got this with only

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-static-programs=fdisk
```

(you shouldn't need any `FLAGS` variables; replace `gnueabihf` with `gnueabi` in your setup, I just used that because I already had a working `armhf` cross-compilation setup).

Comment: Thx for your response. I am not getting any files with .static extensions. I get all sorts of files but .static ones. Not sure what I am doing wrong and why it fails to generate static files.

Answer (score 1):

**Update -- See my other answer below**

Ok, after hours (literally) and hours of analyzing the Makefile file created by the configure script of util-linux and another Makefile file created by another utility that does end up with statically linked files, I successfully retrieved the parameters passed to **arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc** that produce statically linked files. So I ended up with this:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -ffloat-store -static -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -static  -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -o <name_of_your_file> <object files produced by the compiler separated by space>
```

So after compiling **whereis**:

```
make whereis
```

I then did a search for all the object files produced:

```
find . -name "*.o"
```

I ended up with:

```
./misc-utils/whereis.o
./lib/libcommon_la-blkdev.o
./lib/libcommon_la-sysfs.o
./lib/libcommon_la-idcache.o
./lib/libcommon_la-procutils.o
./lib/libcommon_la-mbsalign.o
./lib/libcommon_la-linux_version.o
./lib/libcommon_la-env.o
./lib/libcommon_la-pager.o
./lib/libcommon_la-strutils.o
./lib/libcommon_la-mangle.o
./lib/libcommon_la-timeutils.o
./lib/libcommon_la-fileutils.o
./lib/libcommon_la-exec_shell.o
./lib/libcommon_la-match.o
./lib/libcommon_la-crc32.o
./lib/libcommon_la-md5.o
./lib/libcommon_la-randutils.o
./lib/libcommon_la-ttyutils.o
./lib/libcommon_la-cpuset.o
./lib/libcommon_la-color-names.o
./lib/libcommon_la-ismounted.o
./lib/libcommon_la-path.o
./lib/libcommon_la-canonicalize.o
./lib/libcommon_la-loopdev.o
./lib/libcommon_la-setproctitle.o
./lib/libcommon_la-strv.o
```

So then I consolidated all those object files into one line and I ran another command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -ffloat-store -static -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -static  -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -o mywhereis ./misc-utils/whereis.o ./lib/libcommon_la-blkdev.o ./lib/libcommon_la-sysfs.o ./lib/libcommon_la-idcache.o ./lib/libcommon_la-procutils.o ./lib/libcommon_la-mbsalign.o ./lib/libcommon_la-linux_version.o ./lib/libcommon_la-env.o ./lib/libcommon_la-pager.o ./lib/libcommon_la-strutils.o ./lib/libcommon_la-mangle.o ./lib/libcommon_la-timeutils.o ./lib/libcommon_la-fileutils.o ./lib/libcommon_la-exec_shell.o ./lib/libcommon_la-match.o ./lib/libcommon_la-crc32.o ./lib/libcommon_la-md5.o ./lib/libcommon_la-randutils.o ./lib/libcommon_la-ttyutils.o ./lib/libcommon_la-cpuset.o ./lib/libcommon_la-color-names.o ./lib/libcommon_la-ismounted.o ./lib/libcommon_la-path.o ./lib/libcommon_la-canonicalize.o ./lib/libcommon_la-loopdev.o ./lib/libcommon_la-setproctitle.o ./lib/libcommon_la-strv.o
```

And voila! :) mywhereis got generated.

So I then did the honors by running the file command:

```
mywhereis: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a5b7c4ad147dc26ed211a7aa643f744a29e477f3, not stripped
```

What a relieve!! Ok the solution is not ideal *but* it does the job and in can be streamlined!

I spent about 8 hours in total working on this and experimenting and I realized there may not be "one fix for all" but this does indeed do the job! I tested the file on my Android phone and it works!!

Also, this solution appears to be a "one fix for all" as it just links the object files to create a statically linked file. I tested this with another utility from a completely different source package and that too worked.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to get the whole set of programms statically linked, turns out only a few can be produced in such a way:

From `configure.h`:

```
  --enable-static-programs=LIST
                          link static the programs in LIST (comma-separated,
                          supported for losetup, mount, umount, fdisk, sfdisk,
                          blkid, nsenter, unshare)
```

I need `lsblk` to be statically linked, and it does not work even if I add it to the list (others do). Is there a way to get other static versions outside that list?